# [catkin] Examples for Environment Hooks that work in both devel- and install-space, referencing directories? (empy?)

Tags: ros, catkin, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any examples of creating environment hooks in catkin that work in both devel-space and install-space?

From the [CMake API](http://docs.ros.org/fuerte/api/catkin/html/macros.html#catkin_add_env_hooks), I saw that one of the two methods for handling conditionals inside of the template file is to use the basic CMake template engine or use [empy](http://www.alcyone.com/pyos/empy/) with `*.em` files.

I tried out `empy`, but wasn't sure how CMake variables are communicated.
My next step is to dig a little more into the catkin docs and code to see what environment variables relate to devel-space and install-space.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127421/%5Bcatkin%5D-examples-for-environment-hooks-that-work-in-both-devel--and-install-space,-referencing-directories?-(empy?)/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2014-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `.em` templates for environment hooks only the following variables are available from the CMake context: https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/indigo-devel/cmake/templates/env-hook.context.py.in

If you need additional custom variables in your template you have to use `.in` files (which are expanded by the CMake `configure_file` function which will pass all CMake variable to the template).

Independent of the template type you can either use one template which conditionally deals with devel and install space (https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/hydro-devel/core/rosbuild/env-hooks/10.rosbuild.sh.em) or you can use separate templates for both. In that case you distinguish the template by inserting `develspace` / `installspace` between the filename and the extension (http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-add-env-hooks).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2014-02-08**:
Ah, that makes sense! I had missed the point of the develspace / installspace extensions. And thank you for the empy reference.

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2014-02-09**:
Got to play around with these a bit -- very nice! (More) props to you, Troy, Morten, and Gerkey!